# snmp get value from a file

Tags: linux, snmp, snmpd

I've a script getting value in form of 33333 or 23939 etc. i.e. ./script output: 24310

Is there any possibility that i could monitor in nms over snmp by using the above value. If the value is greater than 20000 then host is up else host is up.

Can anyone let me know that how can i transfer this value to snmp server?

I got the solution from snmpd.conf thanks. I'm using the following

exec .1.3.6.1.4.1.2021.9100.10 NAMEOFMYSCRIPT /path/to/your/script

.9100.10 is custom OID i added by myself.
.1.3.6.1.4.1.2021 was given by snmpd.conf
NAMEOFMYSCRIPT set this whatever you want to.

Solved :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at the exec section of the net-snmp [man page](http://net-snmp.sourceforge.net/docs/man/snmpd.conf.html).  As far as getting an snmp server to poll that, it greatly depends on what you're using.